# Concern for reference fatigue

Tags: interviewing, job-search, references

My work references have been contacted for at least 3-4 different jobs in the past 2 years, two of which I was hired for, but I no longer work at either thanks to a 1.5 hour commute that drained me and another job that just used me for a month long project.

I am getting concerned that if my references are being contacted at this frequency, that their opinion of me will either change or that it will just be getting too annoying for them to follow-up with.

I just had a possible employer who has asked again for my references after an in-person interview. So obviously, I've made it to the next stage, but we still haven't spoken about compensation nor the terms of my employment (probationary period) for example.

I am in the middle of drafting an email inviting them to just check my LinkedIn references and saying that if its necessary that they need their contact information and if its dependent on an incoming offer that I can provide it.

How do you suggest I proceed to prevent this reference fatigue?

Answer (score 4):

> I am getting concerned that if my references are being contacted at this frequency, that their opinion of me will either change or that it will just be getting too annoying for them to follow-up with.

Although a valid concern, this is just speculation. I suggest you **call or meet those references**, and ask them if they are willing to continue to give you such help<sup>1</sup>.

This is the only way you will actually know if they are or not able to provide reference for you this time.

Usually if you say *yes* to someone asking for your reference you *expect* to be called, prompted, etc., so if they accepted chances are they are prepared for this.

---

<sup>1</sup> we should also remember that when providing references you *always* have to check with that person if it is ok to list them as such; that way every time you are applying for something different you are giving them the chance to decline. If they agree again, then proceed without worries.

Comment: If you check with them each time, that just doubles the reference fatigue lol.

Comment: The hiring process is difficult enough for applicants who are already employed.  I believe that requesting job references for any position that is not in upper management or requiring a great deal of trust is antiquated and unnecessary.  Furthermore, I have heard confessions from several people anecdotally that they use their friends to pose as fake references which would be difficult if not impossible for the prospective employer to verify.  Contract-to-hire seems like a more reasonable approach if they're worried about personal character.